# How to run any powershell script located on server to all machines in that network

Tags: powershell

I have 1 powershell script file which i want to keep it on server machine, and want to run it on all machines in that network from server.

Can you please help me in that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your environment?  Do you have PSRemoting enabled?  Are the machines going to pull the script and run it, or is the server going to remotely invoke it on the machines?

Comment: I have windows 7 OS. No, PSRemoting is not enabled. I am trying it by using WinRM, and server is going to remotely invoke it on the machines.

Comment: WinRM is not going to work if you don't enable remoting on the target machines.

Comment: You could use `psexec` if you don't want to/can't enable PSRemoting.

Comment: I have installed PSTools and executed psexec command, but I end up with this error: Access is denied....I am using this command: PsExec.exe \remotemachinename -u FTINDIA\uname -p pwd "filepath"...I think problem will solve once I will get admin crendetials...am I right? I am trying this command on my local machine.

Comment: I am using command: PsExec.exe \remotemachinename -u domain\uname -p pwd "d:\myfile.ps1"...Here I am getting error..The system can not find specified file...I am giving the server machine path here...so which path should be there..Is there is need to have this file on all machines.

Comment: Thank you all, psexec helped me, my script is running successfully.